# jQuery count LI-elements inside UL and get the number of the currently hovered

Tags: jquery, count, hover, html-lists

I have a `<ul>` like the one below;

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Next to that I have a DIV containing another list with images. As below;

```
<ul>
  <li><img src="example1.png" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img src="example2.png" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img src="example3.png" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img src="example4.png" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
```

Technically what I am trying to do is that when I hover an `<li>` of the first list, that it displays the correct `<li>` from the second list.

My guess was to count the amount of `<li>`'s and get the number of the currently hovered one. Then do the same with the second `<ul>` and display the `<li>` with the same number.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIDDLED: http://jsfiddle.net/GTM3X/1/

It's not fancy, but it does what you want.
Let me know if it helps.

EDIT: Adding the code here, for easy access.

```
$('.one li').hover( function() {
    var x = $(this).index();
    $('.two li').hide().each( function(i, v) {
        if (i == x) {
            $(this).show();   
        }
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

Hiya made a small show and hide demo for you **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/KAJsF/

please let me know if this helps,have a nice one, cheers!

**Jquery Code** http://jsfiddle.net/KAJsF/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul li").hover(function(){
        var showcalss = $(this).attr("class");
        $("."+showcalss+"img").show();
    });
       $("ul li").mouseout(function(){
        var showcalss = $(this).attr("class");
        $("."+showcalss+"img").hide();
    });
});​
```

**html**

```
<ul>
  <li class="1">Item 1</li>
  <li class="2">Item 2</li>
  <li class="3">Item 3</li>
  <li class="4">Item 4</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li style="display:none" class="1img"><img src="example1.png" alt="" />SHOW 1</li>
  <li style="display:none" class="2img"><img src="example2.png" alt="" />SHOW 2</li>
  <li style="display:none" class="3img"><img src="example3.png" alt="" />SHOW 3</li>
  <li style="display:none" class="4img"><img src="example4.png" alt="" />SHOW 4</li>
</ul>​
```

Answer (score 0):

See this **example** http://jsfiddle.net/vtENY/3/
The code is self explaining :)

There is no need to change the html markup...the LI index is sufficient :)

I think you might want to hide all LI of the second list if the mouse is not over any of the LI in the first list...this code makes the trick. Let me know...

```
// hide all LI in the "two" UL
$("ul#two li").hide();

// listen for hover/unhover event
$("ul#one li").hover(function(){

    // find the index of the LI to be displayed
    var index = $(this).index();

    // show new active element
    $("ul#two li").eq(index).addClass("active").show();
},function(){
    // hide prev active element
    $("ul#two li.active").removeClass("active").hide();
})
```